# open and save same image again on android

Tags: android, android-image

I am trying to open a saved image in the gallery, and after writing some text on this opened image, trying to close it. But so far, it doesn't work. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong please?

**I checked the path, it is correct. Here is the my code :

```
String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DCIM/100LGDSC/";
String pathiki = path+filename;
Log.d("pathiki:",pathiki);

try {
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathiki);  
  Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Helvetica", Typeface.BOLD);

  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
  paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  paint.setTypeface(tf);
  paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
  paint.setTextSize(14);

  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
  canvas.drawText("bla bla bla", 100, 100, paint);

  OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathiki));
  bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
  fOut.flush();
  fOut.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO: handle exception
  e.toString();
}
```

Comment: Check log cat, you may get some hint. Its quite possible that it might be throwing error in over writing the file.

Comment: No error throwe ,when i checked the logcat,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BitmapFactory.decodeFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) always returns an immutable bitmap. Use [Bitmap.copy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy%28android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean%29) to make a copy of bitmap which is mutable. Now perform modifications on the copied bitmap.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathiki).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Update the exception handler code. Either log `e.getMessage()` to `logcat` or use `e.printStackTrace()`.